# Unidentified devices keep appearing in my Windows 10 network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, wireless-router, home-networking

I'm concerned because Windows 10 network page keeps showing weird devices I don't identify as mine. I want to know what they are and if they represent a security thread.

I have already read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1071681/i-keep-getting-unusual-devices-on-my-router) but is not fully related

For instance see these images below

[image: Other devices in the image]

[image]

Comments:

- They never show their IP addresses, only MAC addresses (communication at data link layer?).
- They don't appear as connected on my Router (it seems only to displays MAC for devices with IP addresses )
- If I block the MAC address on my router they go away but something else appears with a different MAC
- I have already changed the WIFI password (not the SSID) and they keep reappearing
- Sometimes my Samsung Smart TV appears displayed using the same pattern (no IP only MAC) but I do recognize this device. Although I don't know why this happens if the TV is off (Samsung spy!). In addition the TV does not know the new WIFI password
- I don't have Ethernet connected devices on the Router
- I have tried to look for the vendors or IDs of the devices MACs and not too useful information has been found (besides I know it is possible to change your MAC to whatever you want on a lot of adapters so to me this is not too useful)
- I can't hide my SSID or use fixed IPs because I have one WIFI connected doorbell-camera that is not advanced enough to handle networks that don't broadcast SSID and I don't have a way to make it use a fixed IP
- My Router doesn't have the option to disable WPS which seems to have been the solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/976750/windows-10-phones-appearing-in-network)

Comment: Have you tried to check the MAC address here (https://macvendors.com/)? It could shed some light on what it actually is (my money is on your doorbell).

Comment: My doorbell has its own IP and appears connected

Comment: Have you checked the MAC address against the database I pointed you to? It could at least tell you who the manufacturer is, and pinpoint the exact device it belongs to.

Comment: Yes I have but MACs can be changed on an adapter. If you root your phone you can make it have whatever MAC from whatever manufacturer you want. The devices I don't recognize have MACs from vendors I don't recognize. It is all I can say. Besides it is often the case where the MAC vendor if for the WIFI chip and device manufacturer is different and bought this chip

Answer (score 0):

This might be normal, if other devices such as phones try to (or succeed)
in connecting to the network.

If you would like to only selectively connect devices,
the router may have the option to restrict connections to known MAC addresses.